# Função para calcular o Dígito Verificador de um código EAN-13

Tags: php, ean-13

> EAN-13 é um código de barras no padrão EAN definido pela GS1, adaptado em mais de cem organizações membros GS1, para a identificação dos itens, principalmente nos pontos de venda a retalho ou varejo de todo o mundo, com exceção América do Norte onde se usa o código de barras UPC.
>
> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAN-13

Eu precisei de uma função para calcular o DV do EAN-13, mencionado no trecho acima. Na ocasião procurei por toda parte e não encontrei nada a respeito.

Depois de conseguir uma solução, vim compartilhar aqui no site, segue no campo de respostas.

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma alternativa:

```
function generateEANdigit($code)
{
  $weightflag = true;
  $sum = 0;
  for ($i = strlen($code) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $sum += (int)$code[$i] * ($weightflag?3:1);
    $weightflag = !$weightflag;
  }
  return (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/16jW76)**.

Foi adaptada deste post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19890444/916193 - talvez eu edite depois com uma original minha, não gostei desse `$weightflag`. Provavelmente eu usaria um `$i%2` e inverteria o laço (com o cuidado de manter da direita pra esquerda).

Comment: Como alternativa, pode por exemplo acrescentar `$code = strval($code);` na primeira linha da função. Demonstração passando o valor como inteiro: https://ideone.com/PN9EHN

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function digito($cod)
{
   $cnt=1; $arr = str_split($cod); foreach($arr as $k => $v){ if($cnt % 2 == 0) { $par = ($par+$v); }else{ $impar = ($impar+$v); } $cnt++; } $par   = ($par*3);
   $res = (floor(($par+$impar)/10)); $res = ($res+1) * 10 - ($par+$impar);                      
   if(floor($res) % 10 == 0){ $res = '0'; } 
   return $cod.$res;
}

// Usabilidade: Ao Chamar a função com os 12 algarismos retorna já com o dígito.
echo IncluiDigito(789100031550);

?>
```

Comment: Segue um local para testar se o resultado está correto:
https://www.gs1.org/services/check-digit-calculator#gtin